What is the VRF input value of the Chainlink VRF off-chain operator?
A VRF accepts a value as input, and produces an output (i.e., the pseudorandom number) and its proof (via DSA).
From Chainlink's documentation, I can't find what the off-chain operator uses as the input. Chainlink declares that Chainlink VRF could produce fair random numbers, which can't be predicted by any single party (including Chainlink itself). So what's the VRF input? Or how does the Chainlink VRF off-chain operator operate?
I understand the process to request and receive the random number. Say we have a Lottery contract which inherits VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus. The steps are:

Lottery calls requestRandomWords on VRFCoordinatorV2.
Inside requestRandomWords, it emits an event RandomWordsRequested which contains many information. All the information is completely computed on-chain, thus is deterministic.
Chainlink VRF off-chain operator notices that a RandomWOrdsRequested event is emitted. It starts doing the VRF things, i.e., using a value as input and generating a proof. (My question here: what is the input?)
The operator uses its EOA to call fulfillRandomWords on VRFCoordinatorV2, delivering the proof to the contract.
Inside fulfillRandomWords, it uses the proof and a blockhash to generate the random number. Then it uses this random number to generate a series of random numbers via a hash-based algorithm.
VRFCoordinatorV2 calls rawFullfillRandomWords on Lottery. This function is inherited from VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus. It checks the msg.sender to ensure only VRFCoordinatorV2 could call this.
rawFulfillRandomWords internally invokes fulfillRandomWords on Lottery, delivering the series of random numbers. We developers should override this virtual function to implement the logic to consume the series of random numbers.

I just wonder how exactly does the off-chain operator operate in step 3. What's the input to the VRF? Is there only one operator or there are many? If there are many, is the VRF input determined in a decentralized way?
If there's only one operator, then it means that Chainlink could control the VRF input, thus controlling the generated proof. Then, it could simply bribes the Ethereum validators to produce a "good" blockhash. Since the randomness is deterministically generated based on the proof and blockhash, controlling both proof and blockhash means controlling the randomness. How could it be fair?

The VRF input from consumer contract is a mix of:

PreSeed.
Blockhash where your transaction is saved.
Please check the comments in the contract VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus.sol.

PreSeed can be calculated based on the info: keyhash, subId, nonce, and consumer nonce when there is a new request submitted by the consumer contract. Check function _computeRequestId in contract vrfCoordinatorV2_5 if you want to learn more details of preSeed calculation.
Once the preseed(and other necessary data) is emitted by the coordinator, it will be detected and regarded as a new VRF request by Chainlink DON. Block hash will also be picked up with the preSeed.
This is the answer to your question "What is the input" in step 3.
To answer your second question:

Is there only one operator or there are many? If there are many, is
the VRF input determined in a decentralized way?

There is only one oracle node to produce a randomness and proof once a time. It is not decentralized since RNG is an in-deterministic transaction. The process of generating a random number is centralized.
To answer your third question:

How could it be fair?

To answer the question, I need to explain a little bit more about VRF. To generate randomness and proof, the algorithm takes 2 params: seed and secret key. Preseed + blockhash = seed, and the private key of oracle is the secret key.
The randomness cannot be controlled by validators or miners since they do not have access to the private key of offchain node. Seed info can be public on chain because randomness is not solely based on that. For Chainlink, randomness is not predictable because seed from the blockchain cannot be predicted. The VRF algorithm is a one-to-one function so the Chainlink node cannot produce a bunch of numbers and select one by itself.
For now 3 ways to generate randomeness:

based on native data on chain
based on offichain computation
based on mix of onchain data and offchain computation.

VRF is the third one and at the highest security level and could be considered "fair" IMHO.
If someone, as you imagine, can control all validators of Ethereum as well as oracle nodes, then this person indeed can control the random number. But given such extreme cases, nothing can be considered as "fair".

Amazing, detailed and really helpful answer!!! But I still think it's possible to control the random number. Chainlink could just run a Ethereum validator node. When it's Chainlink's turn to produce the block, Chainlink is able to do evil things. It could control the seed (which is completely on-chain), in a way that combining its secret key will yield a "good" random number. Nowadays many EVM chains use PoS consensus. Even if Chainlink only stakes 1% of the whole network (which means 1% of the blocks will be produced by it), it's large enough. During its blocks, it could win all on-chain bets

Moreover, since it only takes a single party/node to become a VRF provider, why can't I just implement a VRF myself? It seems not that difficult. Implementing myself will save a lot of money (I only need to rent an AWS machine that keeps running for 365 x 24), which would've been given to Chainlink to request for random numbers. That's a huge amount.

Consider this issue from an economic perspective; without Chainlink VRF, anyone could control the on-chain randomness, which would be less secure. Moreover, if the benefits gained do not exceed the investment in the attack, then such an attack would not occur. MEV exists in the eth, but it does not compromise the whole security of network. Also, "rent an AWS machine that keeps running for 365 x 24)" is much more expensive than using Chainlink VRF, and one cannot keep the reputation with a node only used by himself.
